# Excel, Setting a cap for values that meet a criteria on a column

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm having trouble finding a way to limit the values of a column by setting a cap, but only for some values meeting a criteria.

An example of what I have:

```
>Criteria  |   Value  
>--------- + --------
>No        |    9
>Yes       |    5
>No        |    3
>Yes       |    7
>No        |    6
>Yes       |    4
>Yes       |    2
```

Since those values come from another formula Im making an exact same table but what I want is for the value colum to show me the values that meet the criteria until a cap, let's say 13. (Just the values that meet the criteria, the others have no cap)

So the final result should look like this:

```
>Criteria  |   Value  
>--------- + --------
>No        |    9
>Yes       |    5
>No        |    3
>Yes       |    7
>No        |    6
>Yes       |    1
>Yes       |    0
```

This is an example but there are actually lots of different values columns, so I need a solution that doesn't require an aux column.

Thank you.

Comment: Sum of values for "yes" is 13, but it's more for "no", is it intentional? Do you keep the original column and calculate in a new column / sheet, our do you need to replace your original data?

Comment: Yes. What I need is to set a cap for the values that meet the criteria, but nor the for the others. Since the original data comes from a complex formula it's easier to keep the original column and calculate in a new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your original columns are A:B, put this formula in C2:
`= IF(A2="yes",MIN(B2,13-SUMIF($A$1:A1,"yes",$C$1:C1)),B2)`